# How to add an image background to a Card object in Android Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-layout

I'm working on a Jetpack Compose app that uses `LazyColumn` to display a list of players and I'm trying to add an image background to each `Card` (in composable function ProfileCard) that represents a player.

I'm using a `Box` object to hold the contents of each entry and have declared an `Image` object as its first element.
From my understanding, all elements within a `Box` object are "stacked" so that elements declared later(further down) appear visually on top of elements declared earlier (further up), so I'm not sure why the image background - which is declared first - is rendered on top of my `Text` element declared further down inside the *ProfileContent* composable at `Line#93`:
[image]

Here is a screenshot with the dark honeycomb Image element disabled:
[image]

and here, with the dark honeycomb Image element enabled:
[image]

Somehow, the background image is being correctly rendered **behind** the player icon yet it is rendered **on top of** the `Text` element - although both the icon and text are declared within the same *Row* object.
Anybody have any ideas how to fix this issue and force the background image to be rendered behind both elements instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't render on top of the `TextField`, it looks like its **on top of it** because of the `TextField's` background blending with the `Image` behind it, so it looks like its overlapping them.
[image: OP screenshot]

I tried implementing your code and changed the the `TextField` `backgroundColor`  to `Color.LightGray`.

```
 Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .size(90.dp)
            .padding(top = 6.dp)
            .wrapContentHeight(align = Alignment.Top),
        shape = CutCornerShape(topEnd = 20.dp),
        elevation = 8.dp
    ) {

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {

            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.honeycomb),
                contentDescription = null,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                modifier = Modifier.matchParentSize()
            )

            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start,
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            ) {
                // ProfilePicture() composable
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(80.dp)
                        .clip(CircleShape)
                        .background(Color.Red)
                )

                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(size = 16.dp))

                // ProfileContent() composable
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(end = 16.dp)
                ) {
                    TextField(
                        value = "Text",
                        onValueChange = {},
                        label = { Text("Player Name")},
                        colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                            backgroundColor = Color.LightGray
                        )
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: White Bg]
[image: With Black honey comb BG]

Edit: Refactored and corrected posted solution description from `Text` to `TextField`

Comment: Thanks. Now what about the (grey) background of the Text component? Shouldn't that have also been displayed on top of the image ? (It seems that the image is still displayed above the Text object's background.)

Comment: ok. seems that the initial grey background is actually no background at all. Had to explicitly set it using "colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors( backgroundColor = Color.DarkGray)"

Comment: @OkeUwechue, I didn't realize it was a `TextField` issue until you mentioned it, apologies, I updated my answer and Glad you figured it out!.